# uploadify: IO error

Tags: jquery, httprequest, uploadify, multipartform-data

I've following code for multiple image upload:

```
<SCRIPT>

function render_uploadify()
{
    $("#body_partition_middle").html('<DIV class = "photo_upload_w"><DIV class = "photo_upload" id = "photo_upload"></DIV><BR><INPUT id = "photo_upload_input" name = "photo_upload_input" type = "file"/><a href="javascript:$(\'#photo_upload_input\').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a></DIV>');

    $("#photo_upload_input").uploadify({
            "uploader"  : "/knock/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf",
            "script"    : "/knock/dummy/upload.html",
            "cancelImg" : "/knock/js/uploadify/cancel.png",
            "folder"    : "/knock/js/uploads",
            "multi"     : true,
            "queueID"   : "photo_upload",
            "auto"      : true
        });
}

</SCRIPT>
```

The above function is being called like:

```
<A href = "javascript:render_uploadify()">Upload</A>
```

Well, the GUI is rendered buy uploadify plugin but when I try to upload files, it ends up into IO error.

The request that I'm receiving at the backend is like:

```
POST /knock/dummy/upload.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2:8888
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/*
Content-Length: 2492
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------368d2437ab8d
```

But there is no HTTP request message body.

Could somebody please tell me what I might be doing wrong here!!

Comment: have you tried 'multi':false, ?

Comment: then you probably tried this as well, but add an `<input type='submit' onClick='$("#photo_upload_input").uploadifyUpload(); return false;' />` with 'auto':false

Comment: Did you check that you can post to the HTML file? I had something similar happen when IIS did not allow posting to files with the HTML extention (not a default configuration). Try just changing the file extention to php (in code and on the physical file on the server)

Comment: uploadify is the worst script I had ever used! There are a lot of others working well. Trash It!

Answer (score 2):

Your IIS is limiting the asp request to the default size which is lower than the file you are uploading, I bet it will work for 10k files right now. Check the following link and that will fix it:

http://arulmurugant.blogspot.com/2008/04/request-object-error-asp-0104-80004005.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the rights to write in the destination folder? The upload folder should be 777 or "all users can read/write". Actually Write is the only really required right.

Comment: Well, my concern is not related to folder permissions or even existence. I'm not getting the HTTP request message at all. You can see the pasted HTTP request in the question. There is no Message body...

Answer (score 0):

Does it "look" like the image being uploaded? By this I mean does the progress bar count up to 100%, if you are using the progress bar.

Is the folder that you are trying to write to, have write permissions?

Comment: No. Progress bar shows IO error. Before writing to file its required that HTTP request reaches at the server. Uploadify is not doing that...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Uploadify are you using?

I think it would be worth trying your DOM manipulation on ready() rather than onclick():

```
<div id="body_partition_middle">
    <DIV class="photo_upload_w" id="photo_upload_w" style="display: none;">
        <DIV class="photo_upload" id="photo_upload"></DIV><BR>
        <INPUT id="photo_upload_input" name="photo_upload_input" type="file"/>
    </DIV>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        $("#photo_upload_input").uploadify({
            "uploader"  : "/knock/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf",
            "script"    : "/knock/dummy/upload.html",
            "cancelImg" : "/knock/js/uploadify/cancel.png",
            "folder"    : "/knock/js/uploads",
            "multi"     : true,
            "queueID"   : "photo_upload",
            "auto"      : true
        });
    });
//]]></script>

<A href="#" onclick="$('#photo_upload_w').show(); return false;">Upload</A>
```

Also with "auto":true you don't need the submit link.